# Using Air Quality Sensors like MQ135 to sense dust particles

Tags: sensors

**Using MQ135 (or similar) to sense dust particles in PM**

I was building a Air-purifier system. So, I need to monitor dust particles present in the air. Is it possible to use a gas sensor like the MQ135 to sense dust particles? Since, It can sense very small gas particles. Would it be possible to sense dust particles with it(MQ135 {Cheaper to buy}) or I need to buy a special optical dust sensor {Costly!}

Comment: You class [this](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Grove-Dust-Sensor-p-1050.html) as costly?

Comment: @Majenko: i class that as _very_ expensive; easily 4X the 2nd cheapest part in a build, when gas sensors are only a buck or two... it's hard to get a build out the door for $10-20 if a part cost $15...

Answer (score 2):

The MQ sensors can not be used to sense dust particles. They are [Electrochemical gas sensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrochemical_gas_sensor) which are sensitive for certain gasses. They are not sensitive for dust particles. [Dust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust) is not a gas, but tiny solid particles.